# URL Rewrite Filter not working with query parameters containing special characters

Tags: url-rewriting, filter, seo, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using URL Rewrite Filter to forward some ugly URLs to pretty Urls.
Referring to [Conditions Based On URL Parameters](http://devtidbits.com/2011/11/28/tuckey-urlrewrite-how-to/),
I’ve done something using UrlRewriteFilter which is actually required to make my site Google crawl-able.
Here’s how it goes.

```
<rule enabled="true">
        <note>
            The rule means that requests to /test/status/ will be redirected to /rewrite-status
            the url will be rewritten.
        </note>
        <condition type="parameter" name="_escaped_fragment_" operator="equal">(apple|kiwi|orange)</condition>
            <from>^/mysite/(.+)/(.*)$</from>
            <to type="redirect">/mysite/%{parameter:_escaped_fragment_}</to>
    </rule>
```

It fails throwing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern – %%7.
As my variable contains underscores (_escaped_fragment_), where in it works fine with a parameter variable called ‘friuit’.
Please help me get out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<rule>
<condition name="_escaped_fragment_" type="parameter" operator="equal">(apple|kiwi|orange)</condition>
<to type="redirect">/mysite/%1</to>
</rule>
```

Using the value of a query parameter with `%{parameter:_escaped_fragment_}` would work only with words containing no special characters. where in `%1` (that is % followed by query parameter index) will work for any, which solved my problem.

Comment: Would you like to add and explanation to your code? Code only answers are good, ones with explanations are better :)

Comment: The solution that user3686902 gave worked like a charm!
I'm happy to give 50 of reputation to him. 
@secretformula, He's new to StackOverflow it seems. I can better explain this.
Using the value of a query parameter with %`{parameter:_escaped_fragment_}` would work only with words containing no special characters.
where in `%1` (that is % followed by query parameter index) will work for any, which solved my problem.